# XAMPP does not display php errors

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp

I have installed xampp on ubuntu. PHP is configured to show all possible errors, warnings, notices etc, but when i make an error in php code no error is displayed.

When i copy that file to other computer (debian with native apache, mysql and php set) and open it in browser it shows

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in...
```

as expected, so why xampp with identical php.ini shows just an empty page?

Answer (score 2):

there may be some serever configure mistake
write below as first line at your php page

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
```

**NOTE:** use [Xdebug](http://dev.digi-corp.com/2009/02/xdebug-install-with-xampp-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is

add this line in your `.htaccess` file

```
php_value display_errors on
```

Answer (score 0):

Find your php.ini file. You can find the location by typing `php --ini` in the terminal.

Then look for display_errors and set it to 1. And error_reporting to E_ALL.

This will set the value globally.

If you only need to see errors for a particular script or application:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: I have enabled displaying errors in php.ini:
    error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
    display_errors = On
    display_startup_errors = On

Comment: You might be getting that error because the database on the other computer is not the same. There might not be any error in your application.